# MKPolygon initialization error "Missing argument for parameter 'interiorPolygons' in call" / "Extra argument in call"

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, ios8, mkpolygon

I'm trying to convert the Objective-C code in the MapKit `MKPolygon` reference in [Listing 6-9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1) into Swift.

When I call the function using the

```
 init(coordinates:count:)
```

init function, I get the error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'interiorPolygons' in call

When I call the function with the interiorPolygons argument, I get the error:

> Extra argument in call

Here is the code that I am using.

```
 var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

 points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116)
 points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066)
 points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981)
 points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267)

 var poly: MKPolygon = MKPolygon(points, 4)

 poly.title = "Colorado"
 theMapView.addOverlay(poly)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 points.withUnsafePointerToElements() { (cArray: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>) -> () in
            poly = MKPolygon(coordinates: cArray, count: 4)
        }
```

seems to get rid of the compiler error, but still doesn't add an overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems with:

```
var poly: MKPolygon = MKPolygon(points, 4)
```

are that it doesn't give the argument labels for the initializer and it's not passing `points` as a pointer.

Change the line to:

```
var poly: MKPolygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: 4)
```

(The `points.withUnsafePointerToElements...` version in your update will also work.)

Also note that `var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()` creates an *empty* array.  Doing `points[0] = ...` should cause a run-time error since the array has no elements to begin with.  Instead, add the coordinates to the array using `points.append()`:

```
points.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116))
points.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066))
points.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981))
points.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267))
```

or just declare and initialize together:

```
var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116),
              CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066),
              CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981),
              CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267)]
```

If you still don't see the overlay, make sure you've implemented the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method (and set or connected the map view's `delegate` property):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolygon {
        var polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.cyanColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        polygonRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
        polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 3
        return polygonRenderer
    }

    return nil
}
```

Unrelated: Rather than calling the array `points`, `coordinates` might be better because `points` implies the array might contain `MKMapPoint` structs which is what the `(points:count:)` initializer takes as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks! My answer technically solved my issue, but your answer was much more thorough, and much clearer code.