# Rendering multiple polylines on MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpolyline

I have two sets of coordinates and trying to draw polylines on map view. I'm able to draw a polyline with one set of coordinates but I couldn't able to draw two polylines.

Below is the code...

```
func drawRouteOnMap()
{
    var centerCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(icRouteLat[0], icRouteLong[0])
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
    var centerPosition = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(centerPosition,animated:true)
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid

    routePointer = "one";
    // first route line
    //----------able to draw polyline with this set of coordinates
    for i in 0..<routeLat.count-1
    {
        var fromCoordinate :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: routeLat[i], longitude: routeLong[i])
        var toCoordinate   :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: routeLat[i+1], longitude: routeLong[i+1])
        var locations = [fromCoordinate, toCoordinate];
        var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate});
        var polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count);
        mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);
    }

    routePointer = "second";
    // IC route line
    //------Polyline for this set of coordinates doesn't appear on map view
    for j in 0..<icRouteLat.count-1
    {
        var fromCoordinateIC :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLat[j], longitude: icRouteLat[j])
        var toCoordinateIC :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLong[j+1], longitude: icRouteLong[j+1])
        var locationsIC = [fromCoordinateIC, toCoordinateIC];
        var coordinatesIC = locationsIC.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate});
        var polyLineIC = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinatesIC, count: locationsIC.count);
        mapView.addOverlay(polyLineIC);
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    let route: MKPolyline = overlay as MKPolyline
    let routeRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline:route)
    routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
    if routePointer == "one"
    {
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
    }
    else if routePointer == "second"
    {
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
    }
    return routeRenderer
}
```

The arrays `routeLat[], routeLong[]` and `icRouteLat[] and icRouteLong[]` are two set of coordinates.

Is there anything I'm missing out here? Or is this the right way to implement?

**EDIT**

Updated code based on the suggestions...

```
func drawRouteOnMap()
{
    var centerCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(icRouteLat[0], icRouteLong[0])
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
    var centerPosition = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(centerPosition,animated:true)
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    var polyLine: MKPolyline!
    var polyLineIC: MKPolyline!

    // first route line
    for i in 0..<routeLat.count-1
    {
        var fromCoordinate :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: routeLat[i], longitude: routeLong[i])
        var toCoordinate   :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: routeLat[i+1], longitude: routeLong[i+1])
        var locations = [fromCoordinate, toCoordinate];
        var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate});
        polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count);
        polyLine.title = "one";
        mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);
    }

    // IC route line
    for j in 0..<icRouteLat.count-1
    {
        var fromCoordinateIC :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLat[j], longitude: icRouteLong[j])
        var toCoordinateIC :CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLat[j+1], longitude: icRouteLong[j+1])
        var locationsIC = [fromCoordinateIC, toCoordinateIC];
        var coordinatesIC = locationsIC.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate});
        polyLineIC = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinatesIC, count: locationsIC.count);
        polyLineIC.title = "ic";
        mapView.addOverlay(polyLineIC);
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline
    {
        let route: MKPolyline = overlay as MKPolyline
        let routeRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline:route)
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        if overlay.title == "one"
        {
            routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
        }
        else if overlay.title == "ic"
        {
            routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
        }
        return routeRenderer
    }

    return nil
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Updated code:

```
func drawRouteOnMap()
{
    var centerCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = icRoute[0];
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
    var centerPosition = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(centerPosition,animated:true)
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid

    // first route line
    polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &firstRoute, count: firstRoute.count);
    polyLine.title = "one";
    mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);

    // IC route line
    polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &icRoute, count: icRoute.count);
    polyLine.title = "ic";
    mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);

}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline
    {
        let route: MKPolyline = overlay as MKPolyline
        let routeRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline:route)
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        if overlay.title == "one"
        {
            routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
        }
        else if overlay.title == "ic"
        {
            routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
        }
        return routeRenderer
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is in the second `for` loop:

```
var fromCoordinateIC :CLLocation = 
    CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLat[j], 
              longitude: icRouteLat[j])  //<-- should be icRouteLong

var toCoordinateIC :CLLocation = 
    CLLocation(latitude: icRouteLong[j+1], //<-- should be icRouteLat
              longitude: icRouteLong[j+1])
```

The second line is not visible (or not where you expect) because it is getting the wrong coordinates.

---

There are, however, some additional things (not causing or related to the main issue) I'd like to point out:

1. In the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method, the code is using the outside variable `routePointer` to set the color of the line.  This is not recommended.  *You must not assume when or how often a delegate method will be called.  There is no guarantee the delegate method will be called immediately after doing `addOverlay`.  It's also possible for the delegate method to be called multiple times for the same overlay.*

   For this reason, you must use data directly associated with the incoming `overlay` object to set the renderer's properties.  In the current example, a better alternative is to set each polyline's `title` property to "one" or "second" and eliminate the `routePointer` variable.
2. In the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method, it would be better to first check if `overlay` is of type `MKPolyline` before treating it like one.  You may later want to add other types of overlays such as `MKCircle` or `MKPolygon`.
3. Currently, the code is creating a separate `MKPolyline` for ***each*** line segment in each route.  So if route "one" has 10 line segments and route "second" has 15, the code is currently adding 25 overlays.  This is not necessary.  An `MKPolyline` can draw multiple line segments.  It would be much more efficient to add all the coordinates for a route into an array and *after* the loop, create and add the `MKPolyline`.  That way, you would only be adding 2 overlays.

   Example of creating a single overlay for each route instead of creating multiple overlays for each route (one for each line segment in the route):

   ```
   //First add all the coordinates to an array...
   var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
   for i in 0 ..< routeLat.count
   {
       var coordinate  = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(routeLat[i], routeLong[i])
       coordinates.append(coordinate)
   }
   //Then create a single overlay with ALL the coordinates in the route...
   polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count);
   polyLine.title = "one";
   mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);
   ```
4. It's not necessary to define separate arrays for latitude and longitude where each array is a list of doubles.  It would be much more efficient and will simplify the code significantly to keep a single array of coordinates (of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`) for each route.  An `MKPolyline` can then be created from this array without any looping.

   Example of using single array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s for each route:

   ```
   var routeOneCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.0, -87.0),
                               CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.0, -84.0),
                               CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(31.5, -83.5),
                               CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(31.0, -83.0),
                               CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.5, -82.0)]
   polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &routeOneCoordinates, count: routeOneCoordinates.count);
   polyLine.title = "one";
   mapView.addOverlay(polyLine);
   ```

Comment: God! That made me feel dumb. First of all thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.
I certainly understood 1 and 2. I tried point 3 you said, and I couldn't see the first line on the map only second line shows up.
And I didn't understand the last point (4). I edited my post with updated code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: For point 3: Although the updated code is still creating a separate overlay for each line segment, it should technically work.  If one of the lines is not visible, make sure the coordinates are correct by logging the values.  See if they are what you expect and in a valid range (latitude must be from -90 to +90 and longitude must be from -180 to +180).

Comment: Here's a way to log the values in the for-i loop right after toCoordinate is set: `println("i=\(i); fromCoordinate=\(fromCoordinate.coordinate.latitude),\(fromCoordinate.coordinate.longitude); toCoordinate=\(toCoordinate.coordinate.latitude),\(toCoordinate.coordinate.longitude)")`

Comment: For point 4, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127239/mkpolygon-initialization-error-missing-argument-for-parameter-interiorpolygons) for an example of how to create an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D values for each route.  The example creates an MKPolygon but the same applies to MKPolyline.

Comment: Excellent! I got everything worked out. Appreciate your help. Thanks! I have edited my code, have a look a at it:)

Comment: Is it possible to create a polyline with breaks? i.e pen up and then pen back down?